# Getting the com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException while parsing

Tags: java, json, spring, parsing, jsonparser

My json requestBody is

```
{
    "action": "DONE",
    "email": {
        "29794": "sue@gmail.com",
        "29795": "sue@gmail.com"
    }
}
```

where "email" is a `Map(key,value)`pair and when i am deserializing this using the `objectMapper.readvalue(entry.getValue(),List.class)`, I am getting the following exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'sue': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: (String)"sue@gmail.com"; line: 1, column: 4]
```

Please help where is it getting wrong.

Comment: Put down the full code, I am not able to get what wrong you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

For such a simple mapping

```
HashMap<String,Object> result =
        new ObjectMapper().readValue(JSON_SOURCE, HashMap.class);
```

(where JSON_SOURCE is a File, input stream, reader, or json content String)

Comment: List<List<String>> emails = new ArrayList<List<String>>();  emails .add((new objectMapper().readValue(entry.getValue(), List.class));

Answer (score 0):

Your input is Json Object which corresponds to `Map` and not `List`. So change your code

```
objectMapper.readvalue(entry.getValue(),List.class)
```

to

```
objectMapper.readvalue(entry.getValue(),Map.class)
```